# Forceably waking up an IOS device from Proximity Sleep

Tags: iphone, ios

If I enable the proximity sensor on a device using :

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setProximityMonitoringEnabled:true];
```

It works as expected. However I have a timer running on a background thread, and when 
triggered I'd like the device to wake up. If I call

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setProximityMonitoringEnabled:false];
```

while the screen is off due to proximity sensor, the device does not wake up. Instead I need to move the device again, and it will wake up with the sensor disabled.

Is there a way to force the device / screen to wake up?
Is there an alternative way to save battery life? I believe simply setting the screen brightness to 0.0f does not disable the back light.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method. Don't know if it works for your case.

```
- (void)lightenTheScreen
{     
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];
}
```